# How to use MySQL database with Strapi 4

Tags: mysql, strapi

I've installed strapi 4 on macOS. I want to change strapi to use mysql database instead of default SQLlite. I've been searching for solution but couldn't find.

I can see the db connection in `/backend/config/database.js`
I changed `DATABASE_CLIENT` value to use mysql2 and `yarn build`  and restarted backend but this doesn't seem to pick the mysql as it is still using default SQLlite.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = ({ env }) => {
//  const client = env('DATABASE_CLIENT', 'sqlite');
const client = env('DATABASE_CLIENT', 'mysql2');

const connections = {
    mysql: {
      connection: {
        connectionString: env('DATABASE_URL'),
        host: env('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost'),
        port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT', 3306),
        database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'strapi'),
        user: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'strapi'),
        password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'strapi'),
        ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false) && {
          key: env('DATABASE_SSL_KEY', undefined),
          cert: env('DATABASE_SSL_CERT', undefined),
          ca: env('DATABASE_SSL_CA', undefined),
          capath: env('DATABASE_SSL_CAPATH', undefined),
          cipher: env('DATABASE_SSL_CIPHER', undefined),
          rejectUnauthorized: env.bool(
            'DATABASE_SSL_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED',
            true
          ),
        },
      },
      pool: { min: env.int('DATABASE_POOL_MIN', 2), max: env.int('DATABASE_POOL_MAX', 10) },
    },
    mysql2: {
      connection: {
        host: env('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost'),
        port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT', 3306),
        database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'strapi'),
        user: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'strapi'),
        password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'strapi'),
        ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false) && {
          key: env('DATABASE_SSL_KEY', undefined),
          cert: env('DATABASE_SSL_CERT', undefined),
          ca: env('DATABASE_SSL_CA', undefined),
          capath: env('DATABASE_SSL_CAPATH', undefined),
          cipher: env('DATABASE_SSL_CIPHER', undefined),
          rejectUnauthorized: env.bool(
            'DATABASE_SSL_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED',
            true
          ),
        },
      },
      pool: { min: env.int('DATABASE_POOL_MIN', 2), max: env.int('DATABASE_POOL_MAX', 10) },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys in `/backend/config/database.js` are parsed from `.env` file in root of your project, so, you `DON'T NEED TO TOUCH THAT`.
Other then that, you would also need to manually install:

```
yarn install mysql@2.18.1
```

If you don't have .env file in root of your project you have to copy and rename `.env.example`

The database part of `.env` should look like:

```
DATABASE_CLIENT=mysql
DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1
DATABASE_PORT=3306
DATABASE_NAME=your-database-name
DATABASE_USERNAME=your-database-username
DATABASE_PASSWORD=your-database-password
DATABASE_SSL=false
```